# Getting Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid on aws lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I want to schedule a job to run on Thursday every week but when I used this I am getting an error.

Cron Expression I am using:

```
"Events": {
    "UsedForCorn": {
        "Type": "Schedule",
        "Properties": {
            "Schedule": "corn(0 20 ? * 5 *)"
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
CREATE_FAILED Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: f9186d09-3e27-43db-a58a-5f5288deaa56; Proxy: null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `Schedule` value. You used `corn` instead of `cron`.

```
"Events": {
    "UsedForCorn": {
        "Type": "Schedule",
        "Properties": {
            "Schedule": "cron(0 20 ? * 5 *)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/users/190823/jens figured moments back